# Yesod button click Handler

Tags: haskell, yesod

I want to create a button to delete a database table.
In Yesod, do I need to first create a

```
<form action=@{DeleteTableR}>
 <button method=post>
```

and use `yesod add-handler` to create a handler?
Is this the common pratice?

I don't want to have a route `/deletetable` just for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want to have a route /deletetable just for this purpose.

At the end of the day, you do have to create a yesod handler to drop your table from the database. How are you gonna do that without having a route for that ?

One way of doing this generically would be to have some route like this:

```
/table/#Text TableR DELETE
```

where the `Text` corresponds to the table name. Now you can create a generic handler named `deleteTableR` to delete different tables using different buttons.